# Twitter's Bootstrap 4 - ComboBox Changing line-Height of Items

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need of a combobox styling based on Twitter's Bootstrap, so I'm using [bootstrap-combobox.js v1.1.8](https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox) and bootstrap.min.js Ver. 4.

I'm having problems changing the `line-height` of items inside the combobox produced by Bootstrap DropDown -- they're too big (I don't know if this is can be done in Click Event or on others places).

I've a page with a SELECT tag:

```html
<select class="combobox input-large form-control" name="normal" id="MyCity">
      <option></option>
</select>
```

This tag is filled via JSON and converted to a combobox using:

```
$('.combobox').combobox();
```

Now, when I click on the arrow the combobox is opened and I can select items.

**With the combobox opened the line-height is too big; it should be smaller.**

The HTML code produced when expanded (using the arrow) is:

```html
<li data-value="XXX" class="">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
   <strong></strong>A<strong></strong>N<strong></strong>X
   </a>
</li>
```

Given that i can't find class="dropdown-item" in css, with Firefox Inspector i see that `<a href="#" class="dropdown-item">` is styled with these attributes:

```css
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    ...
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    ...
```

Now, I could change this value with jquery or other methods (without changing the values in bootstrap.css) but the problem is that items are rendered only with click on `<span class="caret">` tag.

I assume that the change should be made in the click event or after this.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Hi, could you possible rework your question. I'm confused as to what you are asking? Are you trying to change the line-height on a click event?

Comment: Is sounds like you're trying to change the `line-height` of items that aren't visible until you click the dropdown menu. If this is correct, then using "jquery or others methods" should work for you. Have you tried that? If so, please post the code you used that isn't working.

Comment: Solved. Thanks.